# How do I refresh customer list in MainForm.cs after clicked Save?

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, I have CustomerForm.cs where customers' first name, last name, and id can be edited or added in try, catch, and finally statement. And when I use this code in a finally statement to call CustomerList() in MainForm.cs it does not refresh for some reason:

```
finally
        {
            MainForm mf = new MainForm();
            mf.CustomersList();
        }
```

In MainForm.cs, this is CustomerList();

```
public void CustomersList()
    {

        da.CommandText = "SELECT Id, FIrstName, LastName FROM Customers ORDER BY Id DESC";
        da.OpenDBConnection();
        da.CreateCommandObject();
        gridCustomers.DataSource = da.FillDataTable();           
    }
```

Why doesn't refresh? Is there a better way to refresh the customer list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It because you creating new form `MainForm mf = new MainForm();`. You should pass reference to existing `MainForm` into your `CustomerForm`. Or you just need to pass callback that should be executed.

1) Something when you create `CustomerForm` :

```
var customerForm = new CustomerForm(mainForm); //pass through constructor
```

In customer form:

```
finally{
    mainForm.CustomersList();
}
```

Customer form constructor:

```
public CustomerForm(MainForm mainForm)
{
    //some initialization stuff
    this.mainForm = mainForm;
}
```

2) Pass callback as constructor parameter:

```
var customerForm = new CustomerForm(CustomersList); //this will work inside MainForm

public CustomerForm(Action updateCustomers)
{
    //some initialization stuff
    this.updateCustomers = updateCustomers;
}
```

Using callback:

```
finally {
    updateCustomers();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the pass callback as constructor parameter method and it worked fine.